# jQuery pop removes the item from end

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this question in reference to
[jQuery convert checkbox selections to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59578397/jquery-convert-checkbox-selections-to-array). 
This works fine. I have modified it to match my requirements. My javascript is like below .
when a checkbox is checked I want to be added to the corresponding ID(which works fine) but when it is unchecked I want it to be removed..so I used `pop`. That works but it removed the last item ID rater than the unchecked item ID

```
`  var arrayPgggoData = pgggoThisElem.parents('.elementor-widget-container').find('.pgggo-sort-container').attr('data-ajax-container');
    var arrayPgggoData = JSON.parse(arrayPgggoData);
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      const [_, taxonomy, __, attr] = $(this).attr('name').split('-');
      arrayPgggoData[taxonomy] = arrayPgggoData[taxonomy] || [];
      arrayPgggoData[taxonomy].push(attr.split('[')[0]);
    } else {
      const [_, taxonomy, __, attr] = $(this).attr('name').split('-');
      arrayPgggoData[taxonomy] = arrayPgggoData[taxonomy] || [];
      arrayPgggoData[taxonomy].pop(attr.split('[')[0]);
    }`
```

Can someone help me out? :|

Comment: `pop()` doesn't take arguments.  It always removes the last element.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop

Comment: `.pop()` is working as expected. *The `pop()` method removes the last element from an array and returns that element. This method changes the length of the array.*

Comment: You want `.slice()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Comment: Or `splice()` to mutate the original

Comment: @Taplar I can't use the splice or slice as i have only value

Comment: @Twisty I can't use the splice or slice as i have only value

Comment: @GeekyOwl then you need to use the value, with `.indexOf()`, to find the start of the index in the Array so you can Slice or Splice properly.

Comment: @GeekyOwl please provide an example of your data.

Comment: @GeekyOwl I had to look at your other post, and it also has the answer for your question there in the selected answer. But I see what you mean, you need to remove the item based on the `attr` variable. Meaning you need to find the index of that element and remove it from the array.

Answer (score 0):

The pop function does as it is supposed which is basically removing the last element you have.

What you need here is `splice(start, positions)` but in this case you'd need to find the position in which the element appears. For this you would need to use `indexOf(element)`.

You'd need something like this:

```js
var index = indexOf(element);
arrayPgggoData.splice(index, 1);
```

You can check [this article](https://love2dev.com/blog/javascript-remove-from-array/) for more information on different ways to remove elements from arrays in JavaScript.

Comment: You are correct, I fixed that part. `slice()` could work too.

Comment: I can't use the splice or slice as i have only value

Comment: You have to find the index of the valule first with `indexOf(value)` and then use `splice()` or `slice()` with that index.