# jQuery convert checkbox selections to array ( when unchecked make it empty)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

There is a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59578397/jquery-convert-checkbox-selections-to-array) but I have a problem . when check box is checked and unchecked i wanted it to be empty but it results in

`{
  "category": []
}`

but I wanted it to empty `{}`

```js
const array = {};

$('[name^="pgggo-"]').on('click', function() {
  const [_, taxonomy, __, attr] = $(this).attr('name').split('-');
  const id = attr.split('[')[0];
  const checked = $(this).prop('checked');
  
  array[taxonomy] = array[taxonomy] || [];
  const index = array[taxonomy].indexOf(id);
  index == -1 ? array[taxonomy].push(id) : array[taxonomy].splice(index, 1);
  
  console.log(array);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="pgggo-list-taxon">
  <li>
    <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="pgggo-category-sep-56[]">
            <div class="icon-box">
                <div name="development">Development</div>
            </div>
        </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="pgggo-category-sep-14[]">
            <div class="icon-box">
                <div name="food">Food (category)</div>
            </div>
        </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="pgggo-home-sep-14[]">
            <div class="icon-box">
                <div name="food">Food (home)</div>
            </div>
        </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="pgggo-category-sep-8[]">
            <div class="icon-box">
                <div name="medical">Medical</div>
            </div>
        </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="pgggo-category-sep-1[]">
            <div class="icon-box">
                <div name="uncategorized">Uncategorized</div>
            </div>
        </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="pgggo-category-sep-2[]">
            <div class="icon-box">
                <div name="wordpress">WordPress</div>
            </div>
        </label>
  </li>
</div>
```

Please help

Comment: seemed I can see the console is printing empty as well. what is the issue? https://jsfiddle.net/hp7of9sk/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well there should be nothing wrong with that. But still if you want to remove the related property, you can use `delete object.property` to delete it when all the items have been unchecked as following

```js
const array = {};

$('[name^="pgggo-"]').on('click', function() {
  const [_, taxonomy, __, attr] = $(this).attr('name').split('-');
  const id = attr.split('[')[0];
  const checked = $(this).prop('checked');
  
  array[taxonomy] = array[taxonomy] || [];
  const index = array[taxonomy].indexOf(id);
  index == -1 ? array[taxonomy].push(id) : array[taxonomy].splice(index, 1);
   
  
  if(array[taxonomy].length == 0){
   delete array[taxonomy];
  }
  console.log(array)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="pgggo-list-taxon">
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="pgggo-category-sep-56[]">
            <div class="icon-box">
                <div name="development">Development</div>
            </div>
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="pgggo-category-sep-14[]">
            <div class="icon-box">
                <div name="food">Food (category)</div>
            </div>
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="pgggo-home-sep-14[]">
            <div class="icon-box">
                <div name="food">Food (home)</div>
            </div>
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="pgggo-category-sep-8[]">
            <div class="icon-box">
                <div name="medical">Medical</div>
            </div>
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="pgggo-category-sep-1[]">
            <div class="icon-box">
                <div name="uncategorized">Uncategorized</div>
            </div>
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="pgggo-category-sep-2[]">
            <div class="icon-box">
                <div name="wordpress">WordPress</div>
            </div>
        </label>
    </li>
</div>
```